# 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit'

Tags: php

I have a problem here.
I created a mail() PHP script to send attachments and you would normally send in your regular email provider. The problem is that I can only send files up to a certain number of characters.
For example I can send a file with this name "New Text Document" but if I try to send a file with this name "New Document of Microsoft Word (3)" it never gets to my email.

Can someone please tell me why this happens?

Here's the code
http://pastebin.com/5PShDq5P

Comment: You need to show some code.  Also, by "up to a certain number of characters", do you mean the file size, or the file name length?  Have you tried with a long .txt file?

Comment: I really don't know how to put code here so I'll just paste it here http://pastebin.com/R3VQhY1g

What I really mean is the name length                    EDIT: I tried New Document of Microsoft Word (3).txt and I didn't get it

Comment: You can edit the code into the question.  Your pastebin link is broken BTW.

Comment: can't make it work fine. wither way there's another here http://pastebin.com/g4TsK48M

Comment: updated the link http://pastebin.com/5PShDq5P

Comment: I realised that the problem could also be because of the server I have this page hosted. 000webhost.